# Colocando scroll em uma tabela para que não passe os limites do tamanho da janela

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css3

Tenho uma tabela que está com muitas colunas. Quero que ela fique no máximo do tamanho da janela. O problema é que ela passa a janela.
Como colocar um scrool caso o conteúdo passe o tamanho da janela na horizontal?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Isso pode ser feito por meio da propriedade css `overflow`.

A `div` em que sua tabela está deve possuir essas propriedade

```
max-width: 100%;
overflow: scroll
```

Como neste exemplo: https://jsfiddle.net/SamirChaves/fs5xuye3/

Qualquer problema, só avisar.

Comment: esse seu código deveria funcionar na minha aplicação. Eu uso o template sb-admin 2.... Eu não sei o porquê de não aplicar redimensionamento de tabelas. Teria mais alguma ideia?

Comment: Você poderia colocar um print de sua aplicação para que eu possar dar uma olhada?

Comment: Resolvi o problema aplicando em uma div no entorno da table. Não sei o porquê da table não aceitar.

Answer (score 0):

Caso alguem esteja com um problema de aparecer scroll na tabela o problema está no `display: grid`:

no meu caso o código estava assim:

```css
 display: grid;
 grid-template-columns: 1fr 350px;

 @media screen and (max-width: 920px) {
    grid-template-columns: 1fr;
    row-gap: 20px;
 }
```

O problema está no `grid-template-columns: 1fr;`. Quando utilizamos ele acaba que da bug no scroll da tabela, quando a tela era maior que `920px` o *bug* não acontecia porque a tabela estava no valor `1fr >> 350px <<`. Acaba que se dua tabela estiver no grid `1fr` ela vai bugar o scroll da div pai.

Aqui está a maneira correta para que não aconteça o *bug*:

```css
 @media screen and (max-width: 920px) {
    grid-template-columns: 100%;
    row-gap: 20px;
 }
```

basta trocar o `1fr` por `100%` e sua tabela que tenha o pai como grid não vai bugar o scroll da div pai da tabela. espero que entenda